# sorted linked list in c++ won't insert

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

I'm trying to create a class for a sorted linked list which inherits from a class for an unsorted linked lists and overrides the insert function, but the program is not inserting the values I give it into the list and I'm not sure why.

Here's my insert function:

```
class SLList : public LList<Elem>
{

public:
    SLList(){LList::LList();}
    ~SLList(){}
    bool insert(const Elem& item)
    {
            Elem curr;
            for(setStart();getValue(curr);next())
            {
                if(!IntComparision::lt(curr, item)) break;
                return LList<Elem>::insert(item);
            }
    }

};
```

this is the rest of my code:

```
// Singly-linked list node
template <class Elem> 
class Link
{
public:
    Elem element;      // Value for this node
    Link *next;        // Pointer to next node in list

    Link( const Elem& elemval , Link* nextval= NULL ) // 1st Constructor
    { element= elemval ;  next= nextval; }

    Link( Link* nextval= NULL ) // 2nd Constructor
    { next= nextval; }
};


template <class Elem>
class List
{
public:
virtual void clear()= 0;
virtual bool insert(const Elem&)= 0;
virtual bool append(const Elem&)= 0;
virtual bool remove(Elem&)= 0;
virtual void setStart()= 0;
virtual void setEnd()= 0;
virtual void prev()= 0;
virtual void next()= 0;
virtual int leftLength() const= 0;
virtual int rightLength() const= 0;
virtual bool setPos(int pos)= 0;
virtual bool getValue(Elem&) const= 0;
virtual void print() const= 0;
};

class IntComparision
{
public:
    static bool eq( int a , int b )
    { return a==b; }

    static bool lt( int a , int b )
    { return a<b; }

    static bool gt( int a , int b )
    { return a>b; }

};

const int DefaultListSize=10;
// Singly Linked list implementation
template <class Elem> 
class LList: public List<Elem>
{

private:
    Link<Elem>* head;       // Pointer to list header
    Link<Elem>* tail;       // Pointer to last Elem in list 
    Link<Elem>* fence;      // Last element on left side
    int leftcnt;            // Size of left partition
    int rightcnt;           // Size of right partition

    void init() // Intialization routine
    {
        fence= tail= head= new Link<Elem>;
        leftcnt= rightcnt= 0;
    }

    void removeall() // Return link nodes to free store
    {
        while( head != NULL )
        {
            fence= head;
            head= head->next;
            delete fence;
        }
    }

public:
    LList(  ) // Constructor
    { init(); }

    ~LList() { removeall(); }  // Destructor

    void clear()
    { removeall() ; init(); }

    bool insert( const Elem& );
    bool append( const Elem& );
    bool remove( Elem& );

    void setStart()
    { fence= head ; rightcnt+= leftcnt ; leftcnt= 0; }

    void setEnd()
    { fence= tail ; leftcnt+= rightcnt ; rightcnt= 0; }

    void prev();
    void next()
    {
        if ( fence != tail ) // Don't move fence if right empty
      { fence= fence->next ; rightcnt-- ; leftcnt++ ; }
    }

    int leftLength() const  { return leftcnt; }
    int rightLength() const { return rightcnt; }
    bool setPos( int pos );

    bool getValue( Elem& it ) const
    {
        if( rightLength() == 0 ) return false;
        it= fence->next->element;
        return true;
    }

    void print() const;
};

template <class Elem> // Insert at front of right partition
bool LList<Elem>::insert( const Elem& item )
{
    fence->next= new Link<Elem>( item , fence->next ); 

    if ( tail == fence )
        tail= fence->next;  // New tail

    rightcnt++;

    return true;
}

template <class Elem> // Append Elem to end of the list
bool LList<Elem>::append( const Elem& item )
{
    tail= tail->next= new Link<Elem>( item , NULL );
    rightcnt++;

    return true;
}

// Remove and return first Elem in right partition
template <class Elem> bool LList<Elem>::remove( Elem& it )
{
    if ( fence->next == NULL ) return false; // Empty right

    it= fence->next->element;       // Remember value

    Link<Elem>* ltemp= fence->next; // Remember link node
    fence->next= ltemp->next;       // Remove from list

    if ( tail == ltemp )
        tail = fence; // Reset tail

    delete ltemp;                    // Reclaim space
    rightcnt--;

    return true;
}

// Move fence one step left; no change if left is empty
template <class Elem> void LList<Elem>::prev()
{
    Link<Elem>* temp= head;

    if ( fence == head )
      return; // No previous Elem

    while ( temp->next != fence )
        temp= temp->next;

    fence = temp;
    leftcnt--;
    rightcnt++;
}

// Set the size of left partition to pos
template <class Elem>
bool LList<Elem>::setPos( int pos )
{
    if (  (pos < 0) || ( pos > rightcnt+leftcnt )  )
        return false;

    fence= head;

    for( int i=0 ; i<pos ; i++ )
        fence= fence->next;

    return true;
}

template <class Elem> void LList<Elem>::print() const
{
    Link<Elem>* temp= head;

    cout << "< ";

    while ( temp != fence )
    {
        cout << temp->next->element << " ";
        temp= temp->next;
    }

    cout << "| ";

    while ( temp->next != NULL )
    {
        cout << temp->next->element << " ";
        temp= temp->next;
    }

    cout << ">\n";
}

template <class Elem>
class SLList : public LList<Elem>
{
public:
    SLList(){LList::LList();}
    ~SLList(){}
    bool insert(const Elem& item)
    {
        Elem curr;
        for(setStart();getValue(curr);next())

        {
            if(!IntComparision::lt(curr, item)) break;
                return LList<Elem>::insert(item);
        }
    }

};
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an unnecessary `break` in your insert loop:

```
 for(setStart();getValue(curr);next())
 {
     if(!IntComparision::lt(curr, item)) break;  //What?
        return LList<Elem>::insert(item);
 }
```

What this does is if the first item is greater than the item being inserted you will end up not inserting anything. If not, the item should be inserted at the list head (assuming your insert code works).

From the indentation I would assume you actually wanted to do:

```
 for(setStart();getValue(curr);next())
 {
     if(!IntComparision::lt(curr, item)) 
     {
         return LList<Elem>::insert(item);
     }
 }
```

You could omit the `{ }` on the `if` statement but it is more explicit and less error prone if you include them.